# how to open a text file after opening workbook in openpyxl Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

i have been trying to append some data on my excel sheet using openpyxl and after that append some data in my text file...for some reason it gives me error whenever i try to open my text file

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import*

path = "students.xlsx"
```

To open the workbook

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
```

Get workbook active sheet object

```
sheet = wb.active
```

data to later append

```
data = (
    (1, "john", 1/5/2022) 
    )
```

appending data

```
sheet.append(data)
```

saving and closing xlsx file

```
wb.save("students.xlsx")
wb.close()
```

problem lies here

```
with open("students.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(data[0]+data[1] + data[2])
```

here's my error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\taha\tools\attendance\quiz.py", line 32, in <module>
    with open("students.txt", "a") as f:
  File "C:\Users\FLH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "C:\Users\FLH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\FLH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 94, in _validate_archive
    raise InvalidFileException(msg)
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support .txt file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm
```

Answer (score 0):

In a quick view, you defined data as a tuple that contains a tuple with three elements.

As a first step to solve should use a list instead a tuple of tuples:

```
data = [1, "john", 1/5/2022]
```

Could you try this and let me know if it solves or you need more help.

Saying “thanks” is appreciated, but it doesn’t answer the question. Instead, **vote up** the answers that helped you the most! If these answers were helpful to you, please consider saying thank you in a more constructive way – by contributing your own answers to questions your peers have asked here.

Comment: no but i no longer need the txt file...i guess openpyxl has a bug that i cannot close the file and treats other openings as its own...idk

Answer (score 0):

The same error has occurred.

In this case I used import:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
```